# Citrus BASICAUTH issue in 2.7.2

Tags: citrus-framework

After upgrading from *Citrus 2.7.1 to 2.7.2*, my (mock) server-side basic-auth stopped working.

Mock config:

```
<citrus-http:server id="mockServer"
                    port="7070"
                    auto-start="true"
                    timeout="5000"
                    security-handler="securityHandler"/>
```

I have a created a [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/tzie0062/citrusframework-auth-issue) to demonstrate the issue.

When using *2.7.1*, everything works nicely. Switching the version to *2.7.2* yields a server-side 406.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is confirmed see [citrus issue #290](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/290). Thank you for pointing to this issue!

There is a workaround as shown in sample project [citrus-sample-http-basic-auth](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-http-basic-auth) with extended Java bean configuration ([HttpServerBasicAuthConfig.java](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/blob/master/sample-http-basic-auth/src/test/java/com/consol/citrus/samples/todolist/HttpServerBasicAuthConfig.java)) fixing this issue in Citrus 2.7.2.